# почему не считывает из файла в бинарном формате в конце программы?

Tags: c++, файлы, память

Все делаю то же самое, но почему то не хочет переписывать. Что я делаю не так?
вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    FILE *f;
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    const int size = 10;
    int a[size];

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        a[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << a[i] << "\t";
    }

    fopen_s( &f, "f.txt", "wb" );
    fwrite( &a, sizeof( int ), size, f );
    fclose( f );

    cout << endl;

    fopen_s( &f, "f.txt", "rb" );
    int a1[size];
    fread( &a1, sizeof( int ), size, f );
    fclose( f );

    int ss = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        if( a1[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
            ss++;
        }

    int *tmp = new int[ss];

    for( int i = 0, l = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if( a1[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
            tmp[l] = a1[i];
            l++;
        }
    }

    fopen_s( &f, "g.txt", "wb" );
    fwrite( &ss, sizeof( int ), 1, f );
    fwrite( &tmp, sizeof( int ), sizeof( tmp ), f );
    fclose( f );

    fopen_s( &f, "g.txt", "rb" );
    int *tmp2 = new int[ss];
    fread( &tmp2, sizeof( int ), ss, f ); //Здесь не хочет переписыать
    fclose( f );

    for( int i = 0; i < ss; i++ ) {
        //а здесь уже ошибка, так как оно почему-то удаляет память которую
        // я выделил для tmp2(в отладчике смотрел)
        cout << tmp2[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: А в в курсе, что ваш код даже не компилируется?

Comment: @PinkTux у меня все компилируется

Comment: @PinkTux может быть вы не в с++ а в си это запустили?

Comment: Ваш `iostream` включает в себя `stdio.h`? Тогда укажите компиятор, потому как далеко не все это умеют. И да, компилирую как C++, само собой. Не хватает как минимум `stdio.h` и `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @PinkTux не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я незнаю как и почему - но оно заработало(раньше делал такое - не помагало)

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<time.h>
 using namespace std;

void main() {
FILE *f;
srand(time(NULL));
const int size = 10;
int a[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    a[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << a[i] << "\t";
}
fopen_s(&f, "f.txt", "wb");
fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), size, f);
fclose(f);

cout << endl;

fopen_s(&f, "f.txt", "rb");
int a1[size];
fread(&a1, sizeof(int), size, f);
fclose(f);

int ss = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (a1[i] % 2 == 0) {
        ss++;
    }
int *tmp = new int[ss];
for (int i = 0, l=0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (a1[i] % 2 == 0) {
        tmp[l] = a1[i];
        l++;
    }
}
fopen_s(&f, "g.txt", "wb");
fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(int), ss, f);    //удалил те две строчки и прописал эту
fclose(f);


fopen_s(&f, "g.txt", "rb");
int *tmp2 = new int[ss];
fread(&tmp2, sizeof(int), ss, f);
fclose(f);

for (int i = 0; i < ss; i++)
    cout << tmp2[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении

```
fwrite( &tmp, sizeof( int ), sizeof( tmp ), f );
```

вы пытаетесь записать сам указатель `tmp` вместо динамически распределенного массива.

Я думаю, вы имели в виду

```
fwrite(  tmp, sizeof( int ), ss, f );
```

В этом предложении

```
fread( &tmp2, sizeof( int ), ss, f );
```

вы хотите переписать значение указателя `tmp2` данными из файла, которые по размеру превосходят размер этого указателя.

Что вам скорей всего нужно, это следующее

```
fread( &ss, sizeof( int ), 1, f );
fread( tmp2, sizeof( int ), ss, f );
```

Имейте в виду, что правильнее будет записать, например, данное предложение

```
fwrite( &a, sizeof( int ), size, f );
```

как

```
fwrite( a, sizeof( int ), size, f );
```